# Is Configuration Information Securely Located in Vue's Main.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, security, firebase-authentication

I started using vue instead of Asp.Net as my client side framework in addition with Firebase Auth for authentication. In all tutorials, they added the firebase auth configuration file to the `main.js` file.
I am a little bit concerned from a security point of view; since vue is a client-side framework, wouldn't it be possible for someone to access the configuration that is inside `main.js` which would create a security hole?

Comment: _"possible for someone to access the configuration that is inside main.js"_  absolutely, yes. _"which would create a security hole"_  no, the client-side Firebase credentials are not useful to anyone else

Comment: Indeed, I am not sure how I didn't stumble across that question! Thanks!
So I guess it is not a security hole since I limit the IP addresses or domains that have access to Firebase Auth? @Phil